# pandas issue with pandas.NaT when changing from pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Since `pandas 0.23.4`, `pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType` is completely deprecated, so I have to use `pandas.NaT` as indicated in `0.23.2` changelog,

```
The type import pandas.tslib.NaTType is deprecated and can be replaced by using type(pandas.NaT)
```

But when I tried the following code,

```
from pandas import NaT
val_type = type(val)

if issubclass(val_type, NaT):
   return 'NaT'
```

I got an error,

```
TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

If I try,

```
if isinstance(val_type, NaT):
   return 'NaT'
```

I got the following error,

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as the deprecation message suggested, you should use `type(pandas.NaT)`, not `NaT` directly. So if you imported the name, you can do `issubclass(val_type, type(pandas.NaT))`.

Comment: This is much more elegant than mine

Comment: @BradSolomon - please check [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/issubclass). You can see how to use it, so you will have to input types, not their instances.

Answer (score 4):

To expound a bit on other answers:

`pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType` is a class, defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/nattype.pyx#L188).

```
class NaTType(_NaT):
    """(N)ot-(A)-(T)ime, the time equivalent of NaN"""
```

`pandas.NaT` (brought into the top-level namespace) is an instance of the class above, defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/01cb440f2953821418e640d163b138518f16fd50/pandas/_libs/tslibs/nattype.pyx#L662):

```
NaT = NaTType()
```

With the reason being

> This is a pseudo-native sentinel value that can be represented by NumPy in a singular dtype (datetime64[ns]).

`issubclass()` requires you to pass an actual class, not the class instance, and using `type(pd.NaT)` will do that for you without directly accessing any "nonpublic" API.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `isinstance()` the actual type you are looking for. In this case, I would do `type(df.loc[knownnatdata)` and use that as input for the method. For example, I filled a dataframe column with `pd.NaT`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[3,4],[3,4]], columns=["a", 'b'])
df['c'],df['d']=np.nan, pd.NaT

    a   b   c   d
0   1   1   NaN NaT
1   3   4   NaN NaT
2   3   4   NaN NaT
```

Then `type(df['d'].iloc[0])` gives me `pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType` (which is still the type in my version, but note that it is still not *JUST* `NaT`)

to which I compare

```
isinstance(df['d'].iloc[0],pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType)
True
```